# Pandas DataFrame serialization

Tags: python, io, pandas

I'm having trouble writing the entries of a pandas dataframe to a stringbuffer.

It's possible to initialize a dataframe by passing a stringbuffer to the read_csv function.

```
In [80]: buf = StringIO('a,b\n1,2\n')
In [81]: df = pandas.read_csv(buf)
In [82]: df
Out[82]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
```

To do the opposite is not straight forward as the `DataFrame.to_csv` function only accepts a string file path.

Is there any good reason for this behaviour? What's the best way to serialize a pandas DataFrame without storing the contents on disk first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty much just an oversight / inconsistency. I created a GitHub issue here for it:

https://github.com/wesm/pandas/issues/765

EDIT: Implemented this today so you can pass a StringIO to `to_csv`, in git master now and will be part of forthcoming 0.7.0 release

Comment: link to issue is broken