# serialize pandas (python) dataframe to binary format

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

This post includes my question but is actually about another question: [Pandas DataFrame serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189425/pandas-dataframe-serialization)

Is there serialization routine like numpy.savez for pandas dataframes? I see I can use hdf5 but I was hoping to avoid this since hdf5 is an extra install and I haven't been able to get h5py up and running on all the platforms I need.

Answer (score 3):

Arg, DataMatrix is the same as DataFrame. There is a 'load' and a 'save' function that seems to work ... I guess the best way to search the docs is using the interactive prompt with ipython.

Answer (score 1):

Can you instead get PyTables ([installation](http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/installation.html)) working on all platforms relevant to you?

In that case you can use directly the [HDFStore class](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables) in Pandas to serialize Panels and DataFrames, potentially with compression, to HDF5.

Comment: Right, I forgot that PyTables is effectively an h5py alernative. I think there was an open or free version just put out too.

Comment: What used to be PyTables Pro was opensourced [more than a year ago](http://www.pytables.org/moin/PyTablesPro).