# Serialization of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a fast way to do serialization of a DataFrame?

I have a grid system which can run pandas analysis in parallel. In the end, I want to collect all the results (as a DataFrame) from each grid job and aggregate them into a giant DataFrame.

How can I save data frame in a binary format that can be loaded rapidly?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772498/serialize-pandas-python-dataframe-to-binary-format

Comment: Nice [blog post](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization) with timings/discussions of the different I/O options

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The easiest way is just to use [to_pickle](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) (as a [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)), see [pickling from the docs api page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/io.html#pickling):

```
df.to_pickle(file_name)
```

*Another option is to use [HDF5](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#hdf5-pytables) (built on PyTables). It is slightly more work to get started but much richer for querying.*

Comment: Their docs seem to need some work. The `.save()` method has absolutely no description.

Comment: @voithos I realised that as I was looking for a link... :(

Comment: [This](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.common.save.html) seems to be the best out there...

Comment: FWIW save will be changed to [to_pickle](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3782) in pandas 0.12.

Comment: Please note [Python 3 - Can pickle handle byte objects larger than 4GB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31468117/562769)

Answer (score 5):

[DataFrame.to_msgpack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_msgpack.html) is experimental and not without some issues e.g. with Unicode, but it is **much faster** than pickling. It serialized a dataframe with 5 million rows that was taking 2-3 Gb of memory in about 2 seconds, and the resulting file was about 750 Mb. Loading is somewhat slower, but still way faster than unpickling.

Comment: to_msgpack is deprecated since 0.25.0.

Comment: Broken link. The project, as noted, must not exist any more (?).

Comment: Relevant issue for the deprecation: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27084

Answer (score 2):

I prepared this answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38927077/900749), which was erroneously marked as a duplicate of this one.

The best method for *speed* is not the best method for *portability* or *fidelity*. Pickle is fast and faithful, but not portable or archival safe. HFD is portable and archival safe, but is slower and can only store DataFrames with certain formats and structures.

**Summary:**

- For sharing and archiving of simple tables, where some changes in fomat are tolerable: `csv`, `excel`, or `json`, depending on your application.
- For perfect save-and-restore, but no portability or archival safety: `pickle`
- For archiving: `hdf`, but not all tables can be saved portably or losslessly in the format. You may need to restructure things and convert some types.

**Details:** We'd like a method that `pandas` already supports with both `.to_format` method in the `DataFrame` class and a `read_format` method in the `pandas` module. In Pandas 1.5.2 these are `csv`, `excel`, `feather`, `gbq`, `hdf`, `html`, `json`, `orc`, `parquet`, `pickle`, `sql`, `stata`, `xml`.

- The formats `excel` and `csv` are highly portable and nice for simple tables. Complicated tables and datastructures won't survive the round trip.
- `json` is also highly portable, but will change the data in the table. `NaN`s will be converted to `None`, numpy arrays may convert to nested lists, etc.
- I'll skip `feather`, `gbq`, `orc`, `parquet`, `sql`, and `stata`. These are specific formats not wholly compatible with the DataTable format. They are either not very portable, or not very flexible. I'll also skip `html`, it can't faithfully save and restore all of the details of a DataFrame.
- `pickle` is the easiest to use for a faithful save/restore. However, it is not portable and not archival safe. Expect pickle files to fail to load correctly in future versions.
- This leaves `hdf`. This should be an achival safe and highly portable format. Many scientific applications read or store `hdf` files. However, python will still need to pickle any dataframe contents that can't be converted to ctypes.

Answer (score 1):

Have to timed the available [io functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html)? Binary is not automatically faster and HDF5 should be quite fast to my knowledge.