# Does pickle randomly fail with OSError on large files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

#### Problem Statement

I'm using python3 and trying to pickle a dictionary of IntervalTrees which weighs something like 2 to 3 GB. This is my console output:

```
10:39:25 - project: INFO - Checking if motifs file was generated by pickle...
10:39:25 - project: INFO -   - Motifs file does not seem to have been generated by pickle, proceeding to parse...
10:39:38 - project: INFO -   - Parse complete, constructing IntervalTrees...
11:04:05 - project: INFO -   - IntervalTree construction complete, saving pickle file for next time.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/project/src/project.py", line 522, in dict_of_IntervalTree_from_motifs_file
    save_as_pickled_object(motifs, output_dir + 'motifs_IntervalTree_dictionary.pickle')
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/project/src/project.py", line 269, in save_as_pickled_object
    def save_as_pickled_object(object, filepath): return pickle.dump(object, open(filepath, "wb"))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The line in which I attempt the save is

```
def save_as_pickled_object(object, filepath): return pickle.dump(object, open(filepath, "wb"))
```

The error comes maybe 15 minutes after `save_as_pickled_object` is invoked (at 11:20).

I tried this with a much smaller subsection of the motifs file and it worked fine, with all of the exact same code, so it must be an issue of scale. **Are there any known bugs with pickle in python 3.6 relating to the scale of what you try to pickle? Are there known bugs with pickling large files in general?** Are there any known ways around this?

Thanks!

#### Update: This question might be a duplicate of [Python 3 - Can pickle handle byte objects larger than 4GB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468117/python-3-can-pickle-handle-byte-objects-larger-than-4gb)

## Solution

This is the code I used instead.

```
def save_as_pickled_object(obj, filepath):
    """
    This is a defensive way to write pickle.write, allowing for very large files on all platforms
    """
    max_bytes = 2**31 - 1
    bytes_out = pickle.dumps(obj)
    n_bytes = sys.getsizeof(bytes_out)
    with open(filepath, 'wb') as f_out:
        for idx in range(0, n_bytes, max_bytes):
            f_out.write(bytes_out[idx:idx+max_bytes])


def try_to_load_as_pickled_object_or_None(filepath):
    """
    This is a defensive way to write pickle.load, allowing for very large files on all platforms
    """
    max_bytes = 2**31 - 1
    try:
        input_size = os.path.getsize(filepath)
        bytes_in = bytearray(0)
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as f_in:
            for _ in range(0, input_size, max_bytes):
                bytes_in += f_in.read(max_bytes)
        obj = pickle.loads(bytes_in)
    except:
        return None
    return obj
```

Comment: Hmmm... is the filepath valid? Please print it before saving.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. It's definitely a valid filepath. Like I said, "I tried this with a much smaller subsection of the motifs file and it worked fine, with all of the exact same code, so it must be an issue of scale." I did a run where I changed *just* the input file size.

Comment: Do you happen to use a FAT filesystem??

Comment: @Udi I use whatever ships with macOS these days. (so I don't think so?)

Comment: @AlexLenail: Default FS on macOS is Journaled HFS+ -- verify that using `diskutil info -all | grep "File System Personality"`

Comment: How big is your swap partition? Can you increase its size to a multiple of your IntervalTree's size and try again?

Comment: @MatthewCole    `File System Personality:  Journaled HFS+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex, if I am not mistaken this bug report perfectly describes your issue.

http://bugs.python.org/issue24658

As a workaround, I think you can `pickle.dumps` instead of `pickle.dump` and then write to your file in chunks of size smaller than 2**31.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for bringing this to my attention. If this workaround works for me I'll award you the bounty. =) It takes a little while to test so give me an hour...