# Any idea with "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" in pickle.dump？

Tags: python, pickle, dump

Below is my code:
In this code I am trying to split and normalize a ".p" file into files with different norms. However, it seems that the split is working but I cannot save them into ".p" files using pickle.dump. Any suggestion for this error?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle 
import gzip


# in this example tanh normalization is used
# fold 0 is used for testing and fold 1 for validation (hyperparamter    selection)
norm = 'tanh'
test_fold = 0
val_fold = 1

def normalize(X, means1=None, std1=None, means2=None, std2=None, feat_filt=None, norm='tanh_norm'):
if std1 is None:
    std1 = np.nanstd(X, axis=0)
if feat_filt is None:
    feat_filt = std1!=0
X = X[:,feat_filt]
X = np.ascontiguousarray(X)
if means1 is None:
    means1 = np.mean(X, axis=0)
X = (X-means1)/std1[feat_filt]
if norm == 'norm':
    return(X, means1, std1, feat_filt)
elif norm == 'tanh':
    return(np.tanh(X), means1, std1, feat_filt)
elif norm == 'tanh_norm':
    X = np.tanh(X)
    if means2 is None:
        means2 = np.mean(X, axis=0)
    if std2 is None:
        std2 = np.std(X, axis=0)
    X = (X-means2)/std2
    X[:,std2==0]=0
    return(X, means1, std1, means2, std2, feat_filt)

#contains the data in both feature ordering ways (drug A - drug B - cell line     and drug B - drug A - cell line)
#in the first half of the data the features are ordered (drug A - drug B - cell line)
#in the second half of the data the features are ordered (drug B - drug A - cell line)
file = gzip.open('X.p.gz', 'rb')
X = pickle.load(file)
file.close()



#contains synergy values and fold split (numbers 0-4)
labels = pd.read_csv('labels.csv', index_col=0) 
#labels are duplicated for the two different ways of ordering in the data
labels = pd.concat([labels, labels])



#indices of training data for hyperparameter selection: fold 2, 3, 4
idx_tr = np.where(np.logical_and(labels['fold']!=test_fold,            labels['fold']!=val_fold))
#indices of validation data for hyperparameter selection: fold 1
idx_val = np.where(labels['fold']==val_fold)

#indices of training data for model testing: fold 1, 2, 3, 4
idx_train = np.where(labels['fold']!=test_fold)
#indices of test data for model testing: fold 0
idx_test = np.where(labels['fold']==test_fold)



X_tr = X[idx_tr]
X_val = X[idx_val]
X_train = X[idx_train]
X_test = X[idx_test]

y_tr = labels.iloc[idx_tr]['synergy'].values
y_val = labels.iloc[idx_val]['synergy'].values
y_train = labels.iloc[idx_train]['synergy'].values
y_test = labels.iloc[idx_test]['synergy'].values


if norm == "tanh_norm":
    X_tr, mean, std, mean2, std2, feat_filt = normalize(X_tr, norm=norm)
    X_val, mean, std, mean2, std2, feat_filt = normalize(X_val, mean, std, mean2, std2, 
                                                      feat_filt=feat_filt, norm=norm)
else:
X_tr, mean, std, feat_filt = normalize(X_tr, norm=norm)
X_val, mean, std, feat_filt = normalize(X_val, mean, std, feat_filt=feat_filt, norm=norm)


if norm == "tanh_norm":
X_train, mean, std, mean2, std2, feat_filt = normalize(X_train, norm=norm)
X_test, mean, std, mean2, std2, feat_filt = normalize(X_test, mean, std, mean2, std2, 
                                                      feat_filt=feat_filt, norm=norm)
else:
X_train, mean, std, feat_filt = normalize(X_train, norm=norm)
X_test, mean, std, feat_filt = normalize(X_test, mean, std, feat_filt=feat_filt, norm=norm)

pickle.dump((X_tr, X_val, X_train, X_test, y_tr, y_val, y_train, y_test),    open('data_test_fold%d_%s.p'%(test_fold, norm), 'wb'))
```

I think the last two lines are most problematic but it could also be the error somewhere else triggered this problem.

Answer (score 8):

Most likely it is caused by a bug in the Pickle implementation that doesn't allow files larger then 4GB to be produced.

> [Python 3 - Can pickle handle byte objects larger than 4GB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468117/python-3-can-pickle-handle-byte-objects-larger-than-4gb)

Comment: @yunnosch I believe I said ".......................damn son", which is an exclamation of surprise (https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=damn%20son). In this case, I was surprised that pickle would throw an error when attempting to serialize objects larger than 4GB to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on Windows 10, Anaconda Python 3.8.5 when using `pickle.load()`. It turns out the file I am trying to read is in the OneDrive folder and it is not available on my computer yet. I wait for a few seconds to let OneDrive finish the downloading and rerun the code. The problem is gone.

This is surprising. I always thought operations on OneDrive files would wait until the files are fetched from cloud rather than fail. But it turns out to be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Python was trying to access a pickle file that was on my OneDrive, and I was not logged into OneDrive. I logged in and the problem went away.